# Como receber uma variável dentro da URL em php

Tags: php, html, banco-de-dados, variáveis

Estou com um problema a dois dias que não consigo decifrar. Preciso que a variável login e senha passados no formulário de login do meu sistema, chegue até a url que recebe o parâmetro do user e password. Dessa forma ele irá entrar de acordo com o login e senha passados no login. Esse é o código que recebe os dados do banco:

```
    session_start();  // Inicia a session

include "./conexao.php";

$login = $_POST['login'];
$senha = $_POST['senha'];

if ((!$login) || (!$senha)){
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Por favor, todos campos devem ser preenchidos!');window.location.href='login.php';</script>";
}else{

    $sql = pg_query("...");
$login_check = pg_num_rows($sql);
    if ($login_check<=0){
        echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Login e/ou senha incorretos');window.location.href='login.php';</script>";
        die();
    }else{
        @session_start();
        $_SESSION['login'] = $login;
        $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
        $arr = pg_fetch_array($sql);
        $_SESSION['nome'] = $arr['usr_nome'];
        //setcookie("login",$login);
        header("Location:index.php");
    }
}
```

Ai eu preciso enviar os dados para esse link aqui:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="../05fev/imagens/unnamed.png" alt="Imagem responsiva" class="img-rounded"/>
    <div id="main" class="caption">
        <Iframe
            src = "http://desenv.../webrun/logon.do?sys=SER&user=(aqui recebe o login)&password=(aqui recebe a senha)">
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Alguem pode me ajudar ??

Comment: Enviar usuário e senha pela URL é uma prática não segura, faria uma requisição com POST.

Comment: verdade, mas como seria dessa forma ? tendo em vista que é uma url externa anexada ao sistema ?

Comment: O seu html e php estão no mesmo arquivo?

Comment: estão sim, no mesmo local

Comment: @BrunoHenriqueGaignouxGomes Se precisar de um tutorial, aqui tem um bom exemplo: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não vou responder a pergunta propriamente dita, pois o conceito geral está muito errado e inseguro.Quebrar todo o seu sistema de login é assustadoramente fácil, pois você cometeu alguns erros bem amadores. Eu vou é ponderar algumas coisas que podem lhe ajudar a melhorar isso:

- NUNCA CONFIE NO USUÁRIO! A regra básica é - filtre TODAS as entradas e escape todas as saídas. Quando você faz um simples `$login = $_POST['login'];` me permite realizar uma [Injeção de SQL](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL) e comprometer todo o sistema. Leia sobre a função [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input.php), ela te ajudará a resolver isso.
- Não use o @ para suprimir erros, isso deixa o código mais lento, além de ser feio e uma péssima pratica.
- [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.pdo.php) é seu amigo, abuse dele.
- Não entendi o porque de duas  `session_start();`

Resumindo, cuidado com essa ideia sua, não coloque isso em produção. Existe milhares de tutoriais sobre login com PHP, procure referencias antes de começar a codificar, ver códigos prontos ajuda você a pensar no seu.

Comment: Ok amigo, obrigado

Comment: Dica: Se não for mais alterar o SESSION adicione `session_close() `, dessa forma se o usuário abrir duas páginas (que possuem session) irá esperar menos tempo.  O motivo é  simples: apenas um pode ler e escrever no arquivo, sendo assim, se duas páginas estiverem sendo abertas/carregadas uma só seria carregada ao fim do processo anterior. Adicionando o `session_close() `, a segunda página poderá ser carregada quando essa função for chamada.